# Удаление класса у элемента

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Почему не получается удалить класс внутри `<li>`?

```js
$('.js-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.triger.active').parent('li.list').removeclass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="item">
    <li class="list">
        <a class="triger" href="#">aaa</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list">
        <a class="triger active" href="#">bbb</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list">
        <a class="triger" href="#">ccc</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list">
        <a class="triger" href="#">ddd</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="js-btn">click</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`removeclass` -> `removeClass` и если надо удалить у ссылки, то parent не нужен

```
$('.js-btn').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.list .triger.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое ) То что надо было!